# C# list users that have a quota on a drive

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2

I create quotas for users on Windows Server 2008 R2 using the following code

```
DiskQuotaControl colDiskQuotas = new DiskQuotaControl();
DIDiskQuotaUser quotaUser = null;
colDiskQuotas = new DiskQuotaTypeLibrary.DiskQuotaControl();
colDiskQuotas.Initialize(location, true);
quotaUser = colDiskQuotas.FindUser(userPrincipalName);
quotaUser.QuotaLimit = qLimitMB;
```

I know how to read the quota associated to a specific user if I have the user principal name.

```
quotaUser = colDiskQuotas.FindUser(userPrincipalName);
return (int)(quotaUser.QuotaLimit / 1024 / 1024);
```

I'm looking for a way to get a list of all UPNs that have a quota for a specific location, so I can remove those that are no longer part of the AD.